# How to get NUnit to test all values in a list, rather than just the first failure

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

Just some example code here, but I have lists of strings that I want to test my functions against.  The part that I don't like is that NUnit stops in each test when the first Assert fails.  I'd like to test each value and report each failure, rather than just the first one.  I don't want to have to write a new [Test] function for each string though.

Is there a way to do this?

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Examples
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ExampleTests
    {
        private List<string> validStrings = new List<string> { "Valid1", "valid2", "valid3", "Valid4" };
        private List<string> invalidStrings = new List<string> { "Invalid1", "invalid2", "invalid3", "" };

        [Test]
        public void TestValidStrings()
        {
            foreach (var item in validStrings)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(item.Contains("valid"), item);
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestInvalidStrings()
        {
            foreach (var item in invalidStrings)
            {
                Assert.IsFalse(item.Contains("invalid"), item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`[TestCaseSource]`](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6) attribute to specify values to pass into your (now parameterized) test method.

We use this a *lot* in [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) to test a lot of cases with different cultures and strings.

Here's your example, converted to use it:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// Namespace removed for brevity    
[TestFixture]
public class ExampleTests
{
    private List<string> validStrings = new List<string> 
        { "Valid1", "valid2", "valid3", "Valid4" };
    private List<string> invalidStrings = new List<string> 
        { "Invalid1", "invalid2", "invalid3", "" };

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("validStrings")]
    public void TestValidStrings(string item)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(item.Contains("valid"), item);
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("invalidStrings")]
    public void TestInvalidStrings(string item)
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(item.Contains("invalid"), item);
    }
}
```

Note that another option is to use [`[TestCase]`](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.6) which means you don't need separate variables for your test data.

Comment: I was using NUnit 2.4 so I'll need to update to 2.5/2.6 to get this.  Thank you